# Can I write multiple RewriteCond options in single line?

Tags: php, .htaccess

i wanna combine multiple rewrite conditions into single line.

Options can be combined like this:

```
Options -Indexes
Options -Multiviews

-> Options -Indexes -Multiviews
```

and i wanna combine RewriteConds too. here is current code

```
Options -Multiviews -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1
RewriteEngine On [QSA]
```

and i wanna change it like this:

```
Options -Multiviews -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d !-f !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1
RewriteEngine On [QSA]
```

is there any way to combine?

Comment: 1. why don't you simply try it? 2. why don't you simply take a look into the documentation of the tool you use?

Comment: The answer is: no you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry you can't. If you try any of the above you would get a 500 Server error. i tried to get a link that explains the basis of htaccess. Please check https://getpostcookie.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ and the [RewriteEngine On] should be placed first. Best pratice and should only be used once per .htaccess file